# Getting an error after using setState with a promise

Tags: javascript, react-native

Code:

```
onDragEnd = {
    (event) => this.setState({ playerMarkerPositionFuture: event.nativeEvent.coordinate })
    .then(() => alert("hello"))
}
```

When the following code gets executed I receive this error:

```
undefined is not an object evaluating
('_this.setState({playerMarkerPositionFuture: event.nativeEvent.coordinate}).then')
```

If I remove the promise everything works as expected so it means that most likely I used the promise in a wrong way:

```
onDragEnd={
    (event) => this.setState({ playerMarkerPositionFuture: event.nativeEvent.coordinate })
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`setState` accepts a callback, but it doesn't return a promise. [See docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> Calls to setState are asynchronous - don’t rely on this.state to reflect the new value immediately after calling setState. Pass an updater function instead of an object if you need to compute values based on the current state (see below for details).

```js
(event) => {
    this.setState({playerMarkerPositionFuture: event.nativeEvent.coordinate }, () => alert("hello"));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

setState doesn't return a Promise. It is most probably a void function.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using a promise to call alert after setState is finished, use a callback instead

```
onDragEnd={(event) => 
this.setState({ 
    playerMarkerPositionFuture: event.nativeEvent.coordinate 
}, () => {
    alert("hello")
})}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
onDragEnd={(event) => this.setState({ playerMarkerPositionFuture: event.nativeEvent.coordinate }).then(() => alert("hello"))}
```

This is a wrong practise of using setState() method. You can only use a callback using `setState()`.

Right Practise:

```
onDragEnd={(event) => this.setState({ playerMarkerPositionFuture: event.nativeEvent.coordinate },()=>{
    alert("hello")
})
```

Have a look at this article:

https://medium.com/@voonminghann/when-to-use-callback-function-of-setstate-in-react-37fff67e5a6c

Answer (score 4):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

so you could use `setState(updater, callback)` to execute code after the state was altered, to be on the save side

Answer (score 4):

If you want use promise ...another solution could be

```
setStateAsync(state) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.setState(state, resolve)
      });
    }
```

and use that ...

```
this.setStateAsync(
     {playerMarkerPositionFuture: event.nativeEvent.coordinate}
 )
.then(() => alert("hello"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
onDragEnd={(event) => this.setState({ playerMarkerPositionFuture: event.nativeEvent.coordinate },() => alert("hello"))}
```